# send mail laravel stmp

Tags: php, laravel-8

I get this message when i try to send mail with laravel:

> Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in
> E:\xampp\htdocs\eCommerce\vendor\symfony\mailer\Transport\Smtp\Stream\SocketStream.php
> on line 154

mail file

```
class VerifyEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    
    public function envelope()
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject: 'VerifyEmail',
        );
    }

    public function content()
    {
        return new Content(
            view: 'Control.auth.Verify',
        );
    }

    public function attachments()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like your script took too long, compared to the allowed length of time configured on the server. Are you perhaps trying to send lots of emails at once, in a loop? It's unclear. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask].

Comment: Increase the max execution time in php.ini file and confirm if that was the issue.